# MediaType utf-8

Tags: java, android, okhttp

Отправляю запрос на сервер

```
RequestBody body = new MultipartBody.Builder()
                    .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                    .addFormDataPart("data",Packet.info(context).toString())
                    .build();
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(url)
                    .post(body)
                    .addHeader("Connection","keep-alive")
                    .build();
            okhttp3.Response response=client.newCall(request).execute();
```

На сервере получаю `data` и вижу там - `"������������, ���������������������� ����������`

Понятно что дело в кодировке, но как ее изменить на `utf-8` для `MultipartBody.FORM`?

Comment: Попробуйте добавить в запрос вот это: `.addHeader("Content-Type", " application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8")`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб пытался, не помогло.

Comment: Возможно дело на стороне сервера. Там может быть на уровне ОС, например, стоять неправильная кодировка.